# If I need a bool to have the option to be set to null as well, am I better off with a nullable bool or a custom enum?

Tags: c#, enums, nullable

Let's say I am detecting options of a program.

These options can be enabled, disabled, or not possible if the programs version number is below a certain limit.

I need to set it to null if the option is not available.

Now, I have two ways to go.

First one:

```
bool? option;
```

Using a nullable bool gives me the ability to set my option to true, false or null. This would work great and fulfill my requirements.

However, I could also use way two:

```
enum{
    unavailable,
    enabled,
    disabled
}
```

Or something similar to that.

Now, if I have the choice, which one is better in terms of memory usage, accessibiliy etc.?

I would say the nullable bool is way easier to use, but I have seen a lot of people being very negative towards nullables, prefering the enum way by alot.

Can anyone clear me up on this?

Comment: this is a matter of opinion. TBH I'd probably use an Enum since a boolean with 3 values seems wrong. Also, the bool might not be set due to a bug at some stage. The enum would also leave room for the number of possible values to increase without needing a rewrite of the application.

Comment: Recently, a lot of criticism is being raised as to `null` values. Most of it is about the undefined semantics of `null`: `null` has no consistent or self-documenting semantics; it can mean "I don't know", or "I don't care", or "That's not relevant", or "An Error occurred", or a million other things. So for the sake of clarity, you may want to avoid the use of `null`s.

Answer (score 2):

I vote for the enum:

- you may want to *add* some other options, e.g. "Obsolete", "NotSupported" etc.
- you may want to *extend* the logic, for instance add `IsOff` if it's either `unavailable` or `disabled` etc.

So

```
public enum OptionValue {
  Unavailable,
  Enabled,
  Disabled
  // Obsolete,    // can be found in earlier versions only
  // NotSupported // say, technically could be enabled but it will do nothing
  // Proposed // in future versions 
}

// if you add some values into OptionValue enum, 
// you have to update this class only, not the whole application
public static class OptionValueExtensions() {
  // If option is available and enabled 
  public static Boolean IsOn(this OptionValue value) { 
    return value == OptionValue.Enabled;
  }
  // If option is either disabled or unavailable
  public static Boolean IsOff(this OptionValue value) { 
    return (value == OptionValue.Disabled) || (value == OptionValue.Unavailable);
  }
}

...

OptionValue myOption = ...

// it's easy with enum (and extension class)
// if myOption is in fact (by whatever reason) is off then...
if (myOption.IsOff()) {...}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there is not a true or false answer but the following are my thoughts on this and what would less smell from my point of view.

I would tend to the enum. As I think it is possible that you would have a 4th value "NotSet" .

From my perspective a "null" state should be evaluated to a semantic value as you coudn't distinguish wether the "unaviable" option is meant or it is not set (due to a bug)

Answer (score 0):

"bool?" occupies 2 bytes in memory. It has an extra byte of overhead beyond a regular bool.

we consider a tristate enum, which can be implemented with a byte backing store. Notice how the semicolon syntax ": byte" is used after the enum type declaration.

Nullable bools can represent three values: null, false and true. But as we saw here, a custom enum type that uses a byte backing store can more efficiently represent these three values. In type safety the approaches are equally effective.
However:
The enum type avoids the overhead associated with wrapping a value type in a generic struct.

[More details](http://www.dotnetperls.com/nullable-bool)

Comment: can you wrap all your text in a quote block since it's copy pasted from your link?

Comment: I'd suggest you make it explicit that you quote from your link, otherwise the answer may be confused for plagiarism and get deleted

Comment: I heard bool occupies 4 bytes (stored as int32) so bool? should be 8

Comment: The memory efficiency isn't nearly as important as the semantics. .NET probably packs booleans as an optimization anyway, as shown by the linked article.

Comment: @vlad `sizeof(bool)` returns 1, not 4.

Comment: @MatthewWatson bool? is not a reference type